# How to implement aws video transcoder using node.js in lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, video

In my current project i need to convert high quality video medium quality ( to save space).
How can i implement AWS trans-coder in lambda using nodes ?
i am storing video in to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow this link -> https://medium.com/@swappyp20/automated-video-transcoding-in-amazon-web-services-using-serverless-approach-ae7560c9890d

Follow these steps :

1. create source s3 bucket ( for store your video/audio file)
2. Set insert trigger with source s3 bucket
3. Create lambda function using node.js to convert video/audio file
4. After convert audio/video file, will store in dest s3 bucket